# How to flash whole emmc as single image using fastboot

Tags: android, u-boot, fastboot

I have a proprietary ARM device with very limited tools and SDK, but I can manage to start an Android bootloader in RAM. On the host PC, I see:

```
# fastboot devices
SERIAL   Android Fastboot

# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 098: ID 18d1:0002 Google Inc. USB download gadget
```

In other words, the device is connected to a PC via USB OTG and it has this Android bootloader running in RAM.

The device has only one emmc and I have a working emmc: image img-4GB (0x0 to 0xE9000000). This image is a custom OS which has nothing to do with Android. It's not Android. The emmc is full of zeros, there is nothing on it.

**How could I flash directly the whole image to the emmc via fastboot without having to load a kernel?**

I'm ready to patch fastboot on the PC if needed. I have tried to play with a partmap.txt file:

```
flash=mmc,0:all:all:0x0,0xE9000000:img-4GB;
```

and wanted to do something like:

```
fastboot flash partmap partmap_emmc.txt
fastboot flash all
```

but it's not working.